# Unable to use checkbox in eclipse with android adt plugin

Tags: android, xml, checkbox, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

I'm a newbie android app developer, beginner really.  I've tried creating a checkbox on the xml layout on eclipse IDE, for some reason when I run app, it just crashes.

It says resource not found. Following is the logcat:

```
     03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934): Process: com.example.checking, PID: 24934
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.checking/com.example.checking.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:672)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1946)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at com.example.checking.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    ... 11 more
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    ... 24 more
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_btn_check_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020003
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2149)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:387)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2072)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(CompoundButton.java:74)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.widget.CheckBox.<init>(CheckBox.java:68)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.widget.CheckBox.<init>(CheckBox.java:64)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    ... 27 more
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v11/abc_btn_checkbox_checked_mtrl.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020004
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2149)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:387)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2072)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:710)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:939)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:879)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.content.res.Resources.createFromXml(Resources.java:2525)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2145)
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    ... 33 more
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
03-11 20:39:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24934):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:9
```

Can someone help me fix this.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you've updated to v23.2 of the support library. I did the same and I had the very same issue. Here's how i fixed it, hope it works for you as well.

*1) Update to the latest version of Gradle (1.5.0 as of posting this) from the Android Tools repo: ensure you have this in your Build.gradle file (the one outside all modules).*

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
```

*2) If you're using Android Studio 1.4, stop it from generating .png files from vector drawables at run time and use the support libraries, support-vector-drawable and animated-vector-drawable, to do the same instead. Add this to your Build gradle INSIDE your 'app' module*

```
android {      
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []
   }  

   aaptOptions {  
      additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"     
   }
 }
```

Also refer http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Comment: thank you!  I just installed the SDK tools for a couple previous versions (apart from the latest one - 23), and it worked.  I'm able to run my app on the device and checkbox works just fine.  Thanks again!

Comment: glad your issue got resolved. however, this would work if you want to work with the latest version of the support library. I would appreciate an upvote or if you could mark this as the answer. others may find this useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Android Design Support Library (com.android.support:design) from 23.2.0 to 23.2.1 may help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade support library to last version (23).

This exception it cause by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_btn_check_material.xml, this is an element from last version of support library

I think you must migrate to AndroidStudio if you are beginner on Android, Eclipse stopped having support google in December 2015

PD: sorry for my english

Comment: Thanks Rosario for your advice.  I will migrate to AndroidStudio soon.  In the meantime however, I have the latest support library installed already.  Yet, it doesn't work.  I uninstalled and reinstalled the eclipse and the adt plugins, but no impact so far.

Comment: if your support library is actual version (23), try import it to eclipse again and then create a reference to your project with the new version required files are not updated , so you must reimport the library

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.checking.MainActivity" >
    <CheckBox 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"/>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: hey thanks I was able to fix the problem, just installed a couple older versions and it worked!